# Java Hashset.contains() produces mysterious result

Tags: java, equals, hashcode, contains, hashset

I don't usually code in Java, but recently I started not having a choice. I might have some major misunderstanding of how to properly use HashSet. So it might be possible something I did is just plain wrong. However I'm grateful for any help, you might offer. So the actual problem:

In a small program I was writing, I was generating very similar objects, which, when created, would have a very specific id (a `string` or in my last iteration a `long`). Because each object would spawn new objects, I wanted to filter out all those I already created. So I started throwing the id of every new object into my Hash(Set) and testing with `HashSet.contains()`, if an object was created before. Here is the complete code:

```
// hashtest.java
import java.util.HashSet;

class L {
    public long l;
    public L(long l) {
        this.l = l;
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return (int)this.l;
    }
    public boolean equals(L other) {
        return (int)this.l == (int)other.l;
    }
}

class hashtest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HashSet<L> hash = new HashSet<L>();
        L a = new L(2);
        L b = new L(2);
        hash.add(a);
        System.out.println(hash.contains(a));
        System.out.println(hash.contains(b));
        System.out.println(a.equals(b));
        System.out.println(a.hashCode() == b.hashCode());
    }
}
```

produces following output:

```
true
false
true
true
```

so apparently, `contains` does not use the `equals` function provided by `L`, or I have some major misunderstanding of the concept ...

I tested it with openjdk (current version included in ubuntu) and the official current java from Oracle on Win7

for completeness official java-api documentation for `HashSet.contains()`:

> `public boolean contains(Object o)`
>
> Returns `true` if this set contains the
>   specified element. More formally,
>   returns `true` if and only if this set
>   contains an element `e` such that
>   `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 28):

Your `equals` method needs to take an `Object`.
Because you declared it as taking an `L`, it becomes an additional overload instead of overriding the method.
Therefore, when the `hashSet` class calls `equals`, it resolves to the base `Object.equals` method.  When you call `equals`, you call your overload because `a` and `b` are both *declared* as `L` instead of `Object`.

To prevent this issue in the future, you should add `@Override` whenever you override a method.
This way, the compiler will warn you if it isn't actually an override.

Comment: To clarify -- if you don't have the signature of your version of "equals" right, then you aren't actually overloading equals, and HashSet (and everything else) will use the original equals method unless it directly knows about class L (like your test code does). To test this, add: System.out.println(a.equals((Object) b)); to your test program -- it should return false.

Answer (score 4):

You're not actually overriding `Object.equals`; instead, you're defining a new method with the same name but different parameters. Notice that `Object.equals` takes an `Object` argument, while your equals method takes an `L` argument. If you rewrite your equals method to take an `Object` and perform the necessary type-checking/casting to `L` at runtime, then your code is work as you expect.

Also, this is why you really should use [`@Override`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why) annotations whenever your JRE supports them. That way, the compiler will complain if you accidentally implement a new method when you intend to override an existing one.

By way of an example, this equals method should work correctly. (And, on an unrelated note, it won't fail if the object being compared to is null.)

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return other != null && other instanceof L && this.l == ((L)other).l;
}
```

Comment: Ha ha, I did indeed. My mental compiler must not be working today. :)

Answer (score 4):

When you are adding objects to a set it internally calls `equals` and `hashCode` methods. You have to override these two methods. For example I have taken one bean class with `name`,`id`,`designation`, then created and added an `employee` object.

```
HashSet<Employee> set = new HashSet<Employee>();
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setId(1);
employee.setName("jagadeesh");
employee.setDesignation("programmer");
set.add(employee);
Employee employee2 = new Employee();
employee2.setId(1);
employee2.setName("jagadeesh");
employee2.setDesignation("programmer");
set.add(employee2);
```

`set.add()` calls internally the `equals` and `hashCode` methods. So you have to override these two methods in your bean class.

```
@Override
public int hashCode(){
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    buffer.append(this.name);
    buffer.append(this.id);
    buffer.append(this.designation);
    return buffer.toString().hashCode();
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object){
    if (object == null) return false;
    if (object == this) return true;
    if (this.getClass() != object.getClass())return false;
    Employee employee = (Employee)object;
    if(this.hashCode()== employee.hashCode())return true;
   return false;
}
```

Here we are overriding `equals()` and `hashCode()`. When you add an object to the `HashSet` method it internally iterates all objects and calls the `equals` method. Hence we overrid `hashCode`, it compares every objects `hashCode` with its current `hashCode` and returns true if both are equal, else it returns false.